# how to get str from fonction cgi.escape() in python

Tags: python, cgi

I want to recover the value string from php file to use cgi modul with python.

In my file .php I have :

```
<input type="password" name="pwd">
```

Then in my file .cgi I want to get my password and escape the speciales caracters :

```
formulaire = cgi.FieldStorage()
pwdStr = cgi.escape(formulaire.getValue("pwd"))
```

T want to use pwdStr in other fonction with parameter, but the type of pwdStr is not str. How I can convert to str ? I tried with :

```
pwdStr = str(cgi.escape(formulaire.getValue("pwd")))
```

but didn't work.

Somebody can help me, please ?
Basia

Comment: What is it if it's not a string? What happened when you tried `str`? And why are you passing it through `cgi.escape`?

Comment: when I try ti print the type I have nothing : print(type(pwdStr)) no message.

Comment: I want to get this value pwd = "jvh-Mko<54" so I have to use cgi.escape() If I understand correctly.

Comment: If you're getting no message, then your code isn't being called at all.